# Using lightkurve to identify a planet

Tags: python, planetary-transits, light-curve

I have gotten LightKurve to work and plot a lightcurve to allow for the identification of possible transits. However is there a way I can get it to run and tell me if there is a possible transit in the data? I know this possible as at TESS they don't go through all the graphs manually but I don't quite know how to do this? If not is there another package that will do this?

Comment: sounds like you should follow this tutorial https://docs.lightkurve.org/tutorials/02-recover-a-planet.html

Comment: Thank you for your response I have already done this and have been able to apply this for my own csv files however I have 20,000 odd light curves and was wondering a way of uploading my files and having a line of code that can identify that possible planet without me having to go through every single graph myself